# Multiple (triple) monitor configuration suddenly broke in 16.04 Gnome

Tags: 16.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop with 3 external displays running 16.04 Gnome.

The laptop (a Thinkpad T450) can support up to 3 external screeens (as long as I keep the built in display off). The external displays are 3x24" Dell 2415 full HD screens. I connect them using displayport via MST daisy chain (tried with a dongle/hub too).

I've been keeping this configuration for about 9 months now, flawlessly.

All of sudden since past week Ubuntu is unable to keep the displays in the right positions or remember the screen numbers. I've been having all sorts of issues since this week:

- at startup, Ubuntu does not remember / forgets the position of the screens
- when I try to reconfigure them, Ubuntu immediately messes up the positioning as soon as I try to realign them in "Displays" or set the primary one
- sometimes, while trying to reconfigure, one screen enters standby, but Ubuntu still thinks its connected and on, while instead it's blank, and there is no way to turn that screen back on until I reboot everything (turning on and off won't work, it may make the situation worse, I ended up having all screens blank and forced to hard reboot)
- even when I managed to realign all the screens correctly, as soon as I leave the desk, and screen lock -> power saving kicks in, the configuration is lost again (seems Ubuntu has troubles waking up displays having entered power saving)
- occasionally I had the whole system freezing while tinkering with the display tool

I've tried (in random order):

- deleting my monitors.xml in .config
- switching/moving cables in the MST arrangement
- turn all on all the screens altogether at startup
- turn on one screen at the time and configure one at the time
- rebooting between each change, or not

There was no change in my setup save for ordinary apt-get updates. I suspect some update broke the multiple displays management :(

Is there any better tool to manage displays than the one bundled with Ubuntu Gnome?

Comment: I solved by updating to 17.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have a triple monitor set up that was working fine in 16.04.  I have just updated to 17.04 and the system starts up with incorrect monitor settings.  My choice of primary monitor is ignored.  The main menu bar starts 3/4 of the way across the middle monitor and finishes 3/4 across the third one.  It can only be raised on the middle monitor and it disappears when one moves from the middle to the right monitor.

The Fix (so far) is to unplug the hdmi cable of the middle monitor, give it a second and plug it back in.  After this my saved settings are correctly used.

Comment: Yeah so that seems to suggest the idea something in the recent updates screwed it up...

Comment: I'd report this bug but I'm not sure where / which component is the culprit

Comment: Whatever it was, I updated to 17.04 and solved it. It's a shame that such a bug landed in a LTS release though and wasn't solved in over one month.